# Why am I getting the NullPointerException error in a If statement containing .equals?

Tags: nullpointerexception

I've tried numerous ways to fix this but I'm just not having any luck. I've heard you get the error by making a null.equals(null) but I set the value before it got inputted. I'm just really lost, can someone explain this?
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       String MenuChoice = "";
       String MenuOption = "nothing";
    System.out.println("Welcome to my Fashion!");
       System.out.println("\n");
       System.out.println("Are You Signing In As An <Employee> Or <Admin>?");
       MenuChoice = inputData.next();
       MenuOption = MenuChoice;

       if(MenuOption.equals("Employee")) {
           Passwords.MainPassword();
       }
      if(MenuOption.equals("Admin"));
      {
          Passwords.AdminPassword();
      }
}
```

My code is not a duplicate because I am involving strings, not variables. Also, only asking about .equals.

Comment: is there is a chance inputdata.next() is returning a null?

Comment: MenuChoice = inputData.next(); debug this line

Comment: What do you mean by debug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: better to compare constants againts variables, `"Employee".equals(MenuOption)`

Comment: Your code doesn't show what `inputData` is, it could be null or return null. Also the StackTrace would contain useful information where the exception occurs.

Comment: Based on you comments and edit: Yes your question is a duplicate, since you only mention that this code throws a `NullPointerException` and you make the assumption that it's caused by `.equals` which you disprove by your comments in the answer below. So the first step is to find out where the exception occurs, this is possible with a full StackTrace (Read: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/8097737))

Answer (score 0):

There may be chance here `inputData.next()` will return `null`
so in that case it will throw NullPointerException

My suggestion is always use `CONSTANT.equals(str)`. by Using this way if `str` is null than it will check in equals method and your code will not throw NullPointerException

so change your code to -> `"Admin".equals(MenuOption)` -> this will resolve your problem.